# Will an inner class get GC'ed if enclosing type reference is maintained?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

To me it seems obvious that it wouldn't get maintained, but I've bee fooled before by subtle features of java, like providing a reference to an enclosing type by parameterizing the constructor of the inner class, all the while being ignorant of the syntax `EnclosingType.this`. I may also be ignorant of some other method of retrieving references to instances of inner classes from their enclosing types. So if I create an instance of an inner class, and don't maintain a reference, but I do maintain the reference to the instance of the enclosing type, will GC ever clean up the inner classes instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the instance of the inner class will be eligible for GC. The inner class instance has a reference to the instance of the containing class instance, *not* the other way round.

Comment: Normally I would ask for a primary reference, but I think the Skeet is one made manifest. Thanks!

Comment: @JoopEggen: Yup, clarified. Not sure why I started with "no" before.